# web.xml in OSGi container

Tags: spring, servlets, osgi

pros! Looks like basic question, but I just can't find what I am looking for.

I have Equinox and want to run Spring in it (bootstraped in Servlet).
I can't use dm-server, nor can I use the http-bridge, just plain standalone Equinox.
On the other side, using plugin.xml http registry servlet extension is not good enough, since I need the fully-blown web.xml in order to bootstrap Spring.

Where should I dig?

Thanks!
Baruch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To support "traditional" (aka legacy) `web.xml` file for webapp deployment you need an implementation of the OSGi Web Applications spec, part of the OSGi R4.2 Enterprise spec. This will allow you to deploy "Web Application Bundles" (WABs) or even plain old WAR files.

There are implementations of this container in both the Eclipse Gemini and Apache Aries projects. Note that the one found in Eclipse Gemini is also found in Eclipse Virgo (the new name for dm Server). You may find that using Virgo will give you a cleaner out-of-the-box experience rather than having to assemble components yourself. Then again I fully understand if it also provides an awful lot more than you really want!

An alternative to this is to move away from `web.xml` and to register servlets programmatically with the OSGi `HttpService`. This should be a lot more lightweight, but I don't know whether it will work for "bootstrapping Spring" — quite a vague requirement.

Comment: Neil, thanks for the answer! By "bootstrapping Spring" I mean is using listener and context-param as described here:http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-create Does HttpService support listeners and context-params?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the tomcat OSGi bundle that will make you to be able to load bundles as war files. The problem there is that your web bundle's name must end with ".war" and all that stands before that suffix is the application name. So if your bundle's name is myapp.war you connect to it with http://your.server.cc/myapp (and as far as i know there's no way to change that)